# Selecting multiple rows satifies a condition

Tags: sql

I have the following output with me from multiple tables

```
Name Number Code

abc 1111    A
def 1122    A
def 1177    B
xyz 1001    A
abc 1117    D
abc 1189    C
abc 1059    B
def 1002    C
```

I need the select rows where name has all codes. Here name 'abc' has all the codes A, B, C, D. So I should get all rows with name abc. Code can have more values like D, E etc

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the unique number of code is 5. if not change the number of unique codes in the having clause.

```
select name,number,code
from
table A inner join 
(SELECT name,count(distinct code)
from Table
group by name
having count(distinct code) >= 5) B
on A.name = B.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by name and count distinct codes. Then keep those names where the count equals the distinct code count over all records of the table. At last select the records with the names found.

```
select * 
from mytable 
where name in
(
  select name
  from mytable 
  group by name
  having count(distinct code) = (select count(distinct code) from mytable)
);
```